# installing dotnet 3.5 service pack1

Tags: .net-framework

I am installing dotnet 3.5 service pack 1 for windows xp but it is showing error message as

D:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\dotnetx35.exe is not a valid Win32 application

how to solve this problem can anyone help me please?

Comment: x86 vs x64? Corrupted download?

Answer (score 4):

Classical sign of a corrupted package. Download and retry.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a bad installation file. You could start by using the .NET Cleanup tool http://astebner.sts.winisp.net/Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip to completely uninstall all Framework bits from your machine and then reinstall the .NET Framework 3.5 redist from http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe.
Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/dd447c66-536e-4dfa-a5db-55c16f145d4b/